# Div 100% width of container minus nav div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following code:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {margin: 0; padding: 0}

    .left {
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100%;
        position: fixed;
    }

    .right {
        background: green;
        height: 3000px;
        left: 200px;
        right: 0px;
        position: absolute;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="left">d</div>
    <div class="right">dafsdsfsdafkdasfjdslkfja;jdfsklsfdjaklfjdkafsjklsdjkfajklfdaksjlfjlsdsfjasdfkjldsa;fksdalfjdsafjdksa;lfjsdlfjaslfdjsafhdasjfhdsakjfhdsakjfjkadsflasfdfadfasfdasfdsfasfdasfdsaadfkljdsalfsafdsafdsaf</div>
</body>
```

Which renders the following [result](http://jsfiddle.net/C8yN9/). How should I resize the right div to fill the entire screen minus the width of the left div, which is 200px? Currently it overflows the screen width, and I do not know why!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need them to have an absolute position?

Comment: You might be able to use relative widths instead of absolute. Try setting `width: 20%;` to .left and `width: 80%;` to .right

Comment: That doesn't get the right result either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an elegant solution, and it can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Mr3y/)

Answer (score 1):

your text in div.right is too long. So you can use

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

also

```
right: 200px;
```

see [in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbagdat/TcCWZ/1/)

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you enter a nonspaced string so navigator dosn´t know how to display it in multi line you can add the css `word-wrap: break-word;` to solve this.

this is your example modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/q4kwy/3/

Comment: The whole point is that its meant to be 100% the remaining width though

Comment: it is but if you dont tell the navigator to break the long words they gonna overflow so using the property word-wrap: break-word;  you tell navigator to break the long word so they fit in the div, if i dont explian my self good, please tellme